# CakePHP some forms immediately redirect without form data on submit

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Working with a site that's been up for several years, worked on by lots of different developers.  Within the last year it had been updated several times, and at some point some of the back-end forms have begun failing.

Looking at Network traffic I can see the form being POSTed (with data) and hitting a "302 Found" then being immediately resent to the same URL with the Request Method being replaced with GET, and no data attached.  No errors are generated.

This is an issue with multiple forms, but not all of the forms.

I realize this is vague, and I'm not looking for a "solution" so much as hoping for suggestions on things to look at, and tests I can run. (current plan is to simply rebuild a broken form piece by piece looking hoping one bit breaks it).

**EDIT:
It looks like the issue comes from forms that also allow you to OPTIONALLY add or edit child records.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this issue, it ended up being hidden fields that were altered with Javascript.

It seems the security for the forms noticed the value had been changed and then just ignored the submission, reloading the page with no input.  in some cases just changing
$this->Form->hidden
to 
$this->Form->input
on any field that was set dynamically was all that was needed to have the form submit as intended.